# Simplifying $2^{\log_2(n)/2}$

Tags: exponentiation

I'm just completely blanking out right now. So can someone please explain to me how $2^{\log_2(n)/2}$ simplifies to $\sqrt{n}$?

Comment: Use that $2^{\log_2(n)}=n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2^{\log_2(n)/2} = (2^{\log_2(n)})^{1/2} = n^{1/2} = \sqrt{n}. $$

First I used that $a^{bc} = (a^{b})^c$ (for $a\geq 0$), next I used that $2^x$ and $\log_2(x)$ are inverse functions, and lastly I used that $x^{1/2}=\sqrt{x}.$